# JSR 223 ScriptEngine, Invocable, Compilable/CompiledScript - do they supplement each other?

Tags: java, javascript, jsr223

I might need some explaining of stuff I haven't found answers for - neither here nor in javadoc or in the spec... (at least until now)

I am building an application which will have to execute Javascript code, with the help of JSR 223. I am interacting with the JS world through a couple of JS objects which are available to me through global variables. This is why I mainly use *Invocable.invokeMetho*d for my calls to JS. (And I create these objects by calling JS constructors through *Invocable.invokeFunction* and set the returned object in a JS var with *ScriptEngine.put()*. The actual code I read in with *ScriptEngine.eval()*)

Now this is a server application, so CPU footprint and execution speed are important. So I discovered *Compilable*. Which brings me to my first question: Why does this interface exist at all? Why don't the different script engines do this internally and transparently?

Ok, but back to the assumption that I have to use *Compilable*. And instead of reading my JS sources with *ScriptEngine.eval* I would use *Compilable.compile()*. Which would return a *CompiledScript* to me. Which has an interface that only offers *eval* methods. But not anything which resembles the API of *Invocable*.

So how do I get back from my *CompiledScript* to *Invocable*? I still want to use that, the API gives me a nice abstraction! :-)

Anybody can help me out with that? (This is all happening on Java 7 with Rhino. But of course migration to Java 8 - meaning Nashorn - is coming soon so I will have to deal with both engines.)

Thanks a lot, 
Torben

**Update**: Ok, now I just discovered that I overlooked some sections in the spec, the ones about Invocable and Compilable. So it seems like I will already get the benefit of compilation when using Invocable (why didn't they mention this in the javadoc?!).

But then I still have a question: How do I import my source code? Will *Invocable* do a quasi-compilation of my code if I import it with *ScriptEngine.eval*?

Comment: Which section of the spec said "will already get the benefit of compilation when using Invocable"?  I believe you, just curious.

Comment: Oh, I don't know anymore, sorry. That stuff is too long ago now and I haven't worked on it since (the project was abandoned)